# Moving specific files with python os library

Tags: python, operating-system

I want to use the Python os module to move individual files from one directory full of photos to a newly created directory. The OS rename (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#module-os) seemed like it would be promising but it doesn't seem to have to capability of moving files over one at a time rather it just renames the entire directory.

```
for i, v in enumerate(directories):
    newpath = "/Users/simonorlovsky/code/carleton_archive/newsreleaseFolders/directories/"+v
    files = os.listdir( newpath )

    #Check to make sure this directory isn't empy
    if files == []:
        print v, "is empty"
    directories[v] = files
    print "Folder:", v
    print "Files:", directories[v]
    filesToCopyOver = directories[v]
    for i in range(len(filesToCopyOver)):
        filesToCopyOver[i]= filesToCopyOver[i][:-3]+"tiff"
    print "Files to move over", filesToCopyOver
    src = "/Users/simonorlovsky/code/carleton_archive/newsreleaseFolders/tiffs/"
    print "Source:", src
    dst = "/Users/simonorlovsky/code/carleton_archive/newsreleaseFolders/"+v
    print "Destination", dst
    print ""
    os.mkdir(v)
    shutil.move(src, dst)
    print ""
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using ```filesToCopyOver``` what is its purpose?  Some code comments would be nice.

Comment: @wwii I was using it to try to hold all of the specific files that I wanted to move. Posted what became my solution below. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use the [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) library in python.  It has a "move" method.  Of course, you could always look up the source code to shutil.move to see how they did it.

Comment: Looks like OP is using ```shutil.move```

Comment: I see that now.  strange.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that I just had a gap in my understanding of what shutil.move actually does. Turns out for the source you can put a specific file not just a directory. That was what was throwing me off.

Comment: @JayAtkinson I would upvote but I do not have 15 reputation points yet. Once again thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up fixing my code. For shutil.move(src, dst) you are able to put a specific file name in for src. Before I was just confused because I thought you could only put in a directory. Thank you everyone for the help.

```
for i, v in enumerate(directories):
newpath = "/Users/simonorlovsky/code/carleton_archive/newsRelease/directories/"+v #path to current folder
files = os.listdir( newpath )
os.mkdir(v)
if files == []: #Check to make sure this directory isn't empty
    print v, "is empty"
directories[v] = files
print "Folder:", v
print "Files:", directories[v]
filesToCopyOver = directories[v]
for i in range(len(filesToCopyOver)):
    filesToCopyOver[i]= filesToCopyOver[i][:-3]+"tif"
    src = "/Users/simonorlovsky/code/carleton_archive/newsRelease/tiffs/"+filesToCopyOver[i]
    dst = "/Users/simonorlovsky/code/carleton_archive/newsRelease/"+v
    if filesToCopyOver[i][0]!=".":
        shutil.move(src, dst)
        print "File moved from ", src, "to", dst

print ""
```